# Nested tables in livecycle fall apart on email

Tags: livecycle-designer

I have a form here with a nested table - where each table can dynamically grow, i.e., the inner table (w/ Transit No and Account No) and the outer table (Accounts by ID No).   Here is an example:

[image: Correctly nested tables]

(Behind the buttons:

- Add - $.parent.tbl.Row.instanceManager.addInstance();
- Remove - $.parent.instanceManager.removeInstance(this.parent.index);   (In
  production I make sure there is at least one row to remove...)

*In the definition for each table I do not have checked 'Repeat Table for Each Data Item'.   This works great.    However I did try with that checked and the outcome was the same.*

**Now**, when I email the form and open the attachment, this is what I see:

[image: Correctly nested tables]

You can see that the second table didn't make it, and apparently a row was added to the inner table in the first, without any data.

Any ideas on what's going wrong here?   And what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not sure what's wrong with your form but I have made a similar form that works - so I can show you how I did it and list a few things that I can think of that can cause problems.
This is what my form looks like and when I e-mail it, it comes out exactly the way it is:
(It has repeatable parent- and childsubforms like yours)
[image: PDF Form Instances Mail Example]
I did it entirely with JS though, no FormCalc and Dollar $igns :D
When a button is pressed I call a function from a Scriptobject.
These are the main parts of my script inside my functions:

- Adding a Subform:
  `var oNewInstance   =   subform.instanceManager.addInstance(1);`
- Deleting a Subform:
  `if (subform.instanceManager.count > subform.instanceManager.occur.min) 
  {
      subform.instanceManager.removeInstance(subform.index);
  }`

And these are my subforms' properties (in German, but you can figure it out :P):  [image: Subform Occurrences]
Your problem might also have completely other reasons though, make sure you don't have any changes in an `initialize`,`docReady`, `preSubmit` and similar actions that occur between sending and opening the sent PDF.
Also before sending it as an e-mail you have to save it in Acrobat as a *Reader Extended PDF*: 
[image: Saving PDF in Acrobat as *Reader Extended PDF*]
Besides that I've noticed that sometimes problems can occur due to the target version (Selectable in LCD under File > Form Properties > Defaults).
It helped me sometimes to set it to the newest one.

Comment: Hmmm, well this bit me again just now.     You solved this with subforms, not using tables.    Clearly giving up some of the table functionality (headers, columns, others...)     However, it works.       One challenge is that I put this new, growing subform inside of a table row - and that isn't growing.    Ughh.    Sounds like - at least for this instance I may have to dump my nice table structure.    (I even had my general purpose table ADA compliant!)

Comment: @PeterGaston yes, I feel you - but I've had too many troubles with tables that I've given up on them almost entirely a long time ago :D - only used them when there's barely any programming logic involved

Comment: Okay, I've got it all working.   I could easily switch to subforms over tables going forward - though I like the graphical ui one gets 'for free'.     Btw, good to find someone else who's an expert at this goofy technology.     (I actually built a mechanism so one can 'hide' validation when one doesn't want a section to be active.    Had to walk the tree and cache state above/beyond what the form does.    Oh, and text fields work really poorly with 50K of text of more - so had to futz there.)     Best!   p

Comment: btw, I just added a new, related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908923/dynamic-tables-within-tables-do-not-preserve-their-values-over-a-save-load.     My guess is that this is an adobe bug...