# Dynamic tables within tables do not preserve their values over a save / load

Tags: javascript, livecycle

Using Livecycle Designer - now Adobe Experience Manager v 6.4.0.xxx, I'm trying to allow my users to create tables within tables in a form.    I'm comfortable with non-nested tables - they work fine.    The problem is that when I nest tables they lose information over a save.     The first row is saved fine, but subsequent rows are not saved.

These are non-trivial tables.    An outer row has, say 5 text fields, some radio buttons, subforms that hide/show based on logic, etc.    The nested table only shows under certain logic - it also has multiple text fields and check boxes.    However, I've simplified this down below - still fails.

Based on [Nested tables in livecycle fall apart on email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660764/nested-tables-in-livecycle-fall-apart-on-email/39976692?noredirect=1#comment100321741_39976692), I decided to toss out tables and nest subforms to gain the same look and feel as tables.    Again, one 'table' built this way works fine, but the subsequent nesting breaks - in interesting/crazy ways - the subform nested in row one gets more rows (instanceManager.count) and subsequent rows lose their textfield information - but radio buttons keep their information.

**What I've done**

- I've rebuilt using subforms over tables.    No love, though interesting weirdness.
- I've toggled the Form Properties / run-time / Preserve scripting changes to form when saved -- I want automatic but I've toggled to manual and back.    (Per https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1281883)
- I've monitored it as best I can - on preSave and postSave the information is there - on initialization it's gone.

**Pre-Save**
[image: Pre Save]

**Post-Save** Totally whacky.   Kept second row (unlike tables) but lost the information in fields.   First row somehow gained another nested row.
[image: Post Save]

I call this from a button 'click'

```
function fAddSfRow(oSfTable) {
  oSfRow = oSfTable.sfRow;
  oSfRow.instanceManager.addInstance(1);
}
```

And, to remove a row - in another button 'click'

```
var oSfRow = $.parent;
if (oSfRow.instanceManager.count > oSfRow.instanceManager.occur.min ) {
  oSfRow.instanceManager.removeInstance(oSfRow.index);
}
```

[Example PDF](http://www.radioshowlinks.com/f/tintbl-v3.pdf)

What I'd like is a nested table with text fields in each that saves/loads.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the best answer I've found is...

Wrap only the table with inner tables with a 'pre-save' and 'initialize'.

**Presave**

- Capture the number of total rows for the outer table
- Capture the number of rows for each inner table
- Capture the rawValue of each field
- Store all this somewhere - say in a hidden text field

**Initialize**

- Set table.row.instanceManager.count for outer table
- Set table.row.instanceManager.count for each row of inner tables
- Reset all rawValues for fields
- do any logic for hiding/showing subforms or whatever

*Ughh.*